# Finding p-value in two-tailed F-test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

[image]
Image and example come from "Mathematical Statistics with Applications 7th Ed". The test is done at the level alpha = 0.10. I am curious how they got a p-value of 0.2010, or rather how they were able to get P(F > 2.079) = 0.1005. When I use R to calculate this, I get 1-pf(2.079,9,13) = 0.1118.

Comment: I get the same result like yours, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-CDF%5BFRatioDistribution%5B9%2C+13%5D%2C+2.079%5D)

Comment: Please do not use images to convey information which better conveyed in text.  See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/.  For an overview of how mathematical typesetting works on this site, please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.

Indeed the quoted statement suggests this is case since it says "$F_{.10}=2.16$" so you would expect the figure for $2.079$ to be noticeably different, as you did

In fact I suspect they could have said $F_{.10}=2.16382$ with less rounding and your R could have asked `1-pf(2.16,9,13)` to get `0.1005` where the difference from $0.10$ is barely noticeable.  So I think the likeliest explanation is that they accidentally used exactly $2.16$ rather than $2.079$